# Inconsistent vim highlighting throughout various syntax

Tags: vim, syntax, colors

I'm building a color scheme from scratch and as I came past the syntax group I noticed a lot of inconsistency overall.

```
hi Comment      ctermfg=129  ctermbg=129  cterm=italic     
hi Boolean      ctermfg=3    ctermbg=none cterm=bold
```

The comments are basically ignored as they should be both purple and italic, instead they're both a different color and not italic. The booleans as well both show a different color but they do appear to be bold.

[image]

```
hi String       ctermfg=10   ctermbg=none cterm=italic
```

The string on the other hand has no trouble whatsoever.

[image]

I used a Javascript and Python file for testing here but it messes up everywhere (CSS, HTML, Rust, C, Shell).

I'm using rxvt-unicode and have no trouble assigning the purple color to the string.

Kind of unsure on how to proceed here. What could be the problem?

Comment: You might find [this template](https://gist.github.com/romainl/5cd2f4ec222805f49eca) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First ensure that you are looking at the correct line, i.e., that code is using the highlight group that you think it should. You could use the following mapping [from the vim tips](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Identify_the_syntax_highlighting_group_used_at_the_cursor):

```
map <F10> :echo "hi<" . synIDattr(synID(line("."),col("."),1),"name") . '> trans<'
            \ . synIDattr(synID(line("."),col("."),0),"name") . "> lo<"
            \ . synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line("."),col("."),1)),"name") . ">"<CR>
```

By hitting <kbd>F10</kbd> it will display the highlight group off the word under the cursor.

If the problem remains you could:

1. switch the terminal to check if it the problem is specific to urxvt
2. ensure that no plugin/setting is interfering by following the procedure on [Vim FAQ 2.5 - "I have a "xyz" (some) problem with Vim. How do I determine it is a problem with my setup or with Vim?  / Have I found a bug in Vim?"](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5)
3. check the [Vim FAQ on syntax highlighting](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-syntax-highlight)

You may also be interested on [ColorSchemeEditor plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2180):

> This plugin provides a GUI tool which simplifies creating/editing Vim
>   colorscheme files.  It consists of a Vim plugin as well as a Python
>   program, and utilizes Vim's command server interface |clientserver|
>   for communications.

Comment: I was pretty dumb. I forgot to hi clear and syntax reset. Thanks a lot though for the effort. This snippet is still very useful!

Comment: @Katpoes Glad you figured it out :)